What exactly does the quantum mutual information measure?
Quantum mutual information (QMI) is often said to be the quantum mechanical analog of Shannon mutual information (MI).
I realize they can be written with the same formula:
$$S_x+S_y-S_{xy} \ ,$$
where $S_i$ is an entropy of a system $i$.
However, the definition of von Neumann entropy $S$ of a quantum system seems to make QMI not analogous to MI. Let me give a simple example to explain my point.
Consider a pure Bell state:
$$\psi=|01\rangle + |10\rangle \ .$$
According to the definition above the QMI will be 2 ($S_x=S_y=1$ and $S_{xy}=0$).
Maybe this is my confusion, but I thought the point of MI was to measure the amount of information gained about 1 system $x$ by measuring another $y$.
In this example, I'd expect QMI to be at most 1. The most we could learn about 1 system by measuring the other is 1 qubit (if we measure on $\{|0\rangle ,|1\rangle\}$). The fact that it is 2 doesn't make sense to me.
So what exactly is QMI measuring?  Are there reasons why it makes sense to have this definition and e.g. have QMI = 2 for the above example?

Alternative perspective: Mutual information is entropy minus conditional information, and the latter can be negative in quantum systems, but not in classical systems. This has an interpretation: Quantum information can be negative

https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FZ-Sp0TUYAEKKlz.jpg

Does this answer your question? What does the "quantum mutual information" quantify?

The QMI measures both quantum and classical correlations at the same time. So in your example, you get two bits because there is both the classical correlation of the spins being anti-aligned, but also the quantum correlation coming from their entanglement.
To see this, let's see what happens when we erase the entanglement by instead considering the global state $$\rho_{xy} = \frac{1}{2}| 01 \rangle \langle 01| +  \frac{1}{2}| 10 \rangle \langle 10|.$$ With this state, we can compute $$I(X,Y) = 1 + 1 - 1 = 1.$$ This is the answer you were expecting: the difference with your example comes from the entanglement.

What you are computing is just the mutual information of a classical state. It is unclear why this allows for the claim that the difference comes from the entanglement -- it could just as well come from the non-classicality. Also, the "classical correlations of the spins being anti-aligned" cannot be separated from the entanglement of the state.

Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Are you saying that there are quantum correlations which do not come from entanglement? I agree that I computed the mutual information of a classical state, in particular an incoherent superposition of $01$ and $10$. This differs from the coherent superposition exactly because of the fact that a bell pair is pure, but has the same marginal distributions as this incoherent superposition. The fact that $S(\rho_x) > 0$ but $S(\rho_{xy})=0$ implies that the spins at $X$ and $Y$ are entangled. But I feel like I'm still missing your point?

No, you have been saying that there is "both the classical correlation [...] but also the quantum correlation". Also, the argument that the marginal distributions are the same is not the point -- this would also be true for the maximally mixed state. I would say the problem is that the claims you make are to general to make a case for this specific situation -- with the same kind of arguments, one could likely argue for something incorrect.

The fact that $I=1$ for this state makes sense to me and seems analogous to normal MI.  I'm still confused as to why it makes sense to have $I=2$ for the pure state I gave.  That QMI sums classical and quantum correlations seems strange to me--then it would seem to lose its meaning as "the amount of information learned about one system by measuring another," right?  I'm not denying your explanation, I'm just surprised the name "mutual information" is used when it's no longer "the information gained about 1 by measuring the other."

entanglement isn't the only problem here. Separable states can also have a QMI larger than the (largest possible) mutual information. See for example what you get computing the QMI of the (separable) state obtained mixing $|00\rangle$ and $|1+\rangle$
